How to move moves calculations to a separate thread in Tkinter?
In the current implementation of checkers on tkinter, despite the fact that it seems to have moved the calculation of moves to a separate thread, the interface slows down when the computer calculates the optimal move (with an average depth of calculation). Without this attempt to put it into a separate thread, the interface simply does not respond, but the animations are reproduced
Here are the key methods:
def mouse_down(self, event: Event):
        '''Событие нажатия мышки'''
        x, y = (event.x - BOARD_BORDER) // CELL_SIZE, (event.y - BOARD_BORDER) // CELL_SIZE
        # Если точка не внутри поля
        if not (self.__field.is_within(x, y)): return
        if MULTIPLAYER:
        ...
        else:
            if not (self.__player_turn): return

            if (PLAYER_SIDE == SideType.WHITE):
                player_checkers = WHITE_CHECKERS
            elif (PLAYER_SIDE == SideType.BLACK):
                player_checkers = BLACK_CHECKERS
            else:
                return

            # Если нажатие по шашке игрока, то выбрать её
            if (self.__field.type_at(x, y) in player_checkers):
                self.__selected_cell = Point(x, y)
                self.__draw()
            elif (self.__player_turn):
                move = Move(self.__selected_cell.x, self.__selected_cell.y, x, y)
                # Если нажатие по ячейке, на которую можно походить
                if (move in self.__get_moves_list(PLAYER_SIDE)):
                    self.__handle_player_turn(move)
                    # Если не ход игрока, то ход противника
                    if not (self.__player_turn):
                        self.test_field = self.__field
                        self.handle_enemy_turn_async()
                ...
    def handle_enemy_turn_async(game_instance):
        def run():
            game_instance.__handle_enemy_turn()

        threading.Thread(target=run).start()

    def __handle_enemy_turn(self):
        '''Обработка хода противника (компьютера)'''
        self.__player_turn = False
        self.calc = True
        optimal_moves_list = self.__predict_optimal_moves(SideType.opposite(PLAYER_SIDE))
        self.calc = False
        for move in optimal_moves_list:
            self.__handle_move(self.__field, move)
        self.__player_turn = True
        self.__check_for_game_over()

    def __predict_optimal_moves(self, side: SideType) -> list[Move]:
        '''Предсказать оптимальный ход'''
        best_result = 0
        optimal_moves = []
        self.test_field = Field.copy(self.__field)
        predicted_moves_list = self.__get_predicted_moves_list(side)
        if (predicted_moves_list):
            field_copy = Field.copy(self.__field)
            self.test_field = Field.copy(self.__field)
            field_copy_test = Field.copy(self.test_field)
            for moves in predicted_moves_list:
                for move in moves:
                    self.__handle_move(self.test_field, move, draw=False)
                try:
                    if (side == SideType.WHITE):
                        result = self.test_field.white_score / self.test_field.black_score
                    elif (side == SideType.BLACK):
                        result = self.test_field.black_score / self.test_field.white_score
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    result = inf

                if (result > best_result):
                    best_result = result
                    optimal_moves.clear()
                    optimal_moves.append(moves)
                elif (result == best_result):
                    optimal_moves.append(moves)

                self.test_field = Field.copy(field_copy_test)

        optimal_move = []
        if (optimal_moves):
            # Фильтрация хода
            for move in choice(optimal_moves):
                if (side == SideType.WHITE and self.__field.type_at(move.from_x, move.from_y) in BLACK_CHECKERS):
                    break
                elif (side == SideType.BLACK and self.__field.type_at(move.from_x, move.from_y) in WHITE_CHECKERS):
                    break
                optimal_move.append(move)
        return optimal_move

    def __get_predicted_moves_list(self, side: SideType, current_prediction_depth: int = 0,
                                   all_moves_list: list[Move] = [], current_moves_list: list[Move] = [],
                                   required_moves_list: list[Move] = []) -> list[Move]:
        '''Предсказать все возможные ходы'''
        if (current_moves_list):
            all_moves_list.append(current_moves_list)
        else:
            all_moves_list.clear()

        if (required_moves_list):
            moves_list = required_moves_list
        else:
            now = False
            moves_list = self.__get_moves_list(side)

        if (moves_list and current_prediction_depth < MAX_DEPTH):
            field_copy = Field.copy(self.test_field)
            for move in moves_list:
                field_for_check = Field.copy(self.test_field)
                has_killed_checker = self.__handle_move(self.test_field, move, draw=False)
                required_moves_list = list(filter(
                    lambda required_move: move.to_x == required_move.from_x and move.to_y == required_move.from_y,
                    self.__get_required_moves_list(side, self.test_field)))
                # Если есть ещё ход этой же шашкой
                if (has_killed_checker and required_moves_list):
                    self.__get_predicted_moves_list(side, current_prediction_depth, all_moves_list,
                                                    current_moves_list + [move], required_moves_list)
                else:
                    self.__get_predicted_moves_list(SideType.opposite(side), current_prediction_depth + 1,
                                                    all_moves_list, current_moves_list + [move])

                self.test_field = Field.copy(field_copy)

        return all_moves_list


You could check and log the name of the current thread in which each method is called, e. g. by creating a decorator for that. The name of the main thread should be MainThread.

Executing 'handle_enemy_turn_async' of Game in thread: MainThread
Executing '__handle_enemy_turn' of Game in thread: Thread-1 (run)
this is what the debugger showed

The point is that all recursive function calls that occur are executed in the same (additional) thread

On a side note: If you are not using classes, there is no reason to use two underscores to prefix anything. A single underscore is a reminder, to human programmers, that the name should be treated as private. Two underscores trigger a name-mangling mechanism which forces the behavior, but just inside class bodies.

In the snippet shown, I see no mechanism that would prevent several calculations of the "enemy turn" to start at once. Maybe you are just starting several such calculations at once, and the slowdown is due to CPU usage?
You can add a single thread as an instance attribute, and reuse it -
...
import queue
...

    def _ensure_calc_thread(self):
        if not getattr(self, "_calc_thread"):
            self._calc_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._calc_thread_driver)
            self._calc_queue = queue.Queue()
            self._calc_thread.start()
            
    def self._calc_thread_driver(self):
        while True:
            # this line waits until there is something on the queue. 
            move_now = self._calc_queue.get()
            # maybe put a special marker in the queue to stop the thread
            # at the end of the game - just add an "if" statement here!
            self.__handle_enemy_turn()
            

    def handle_enemy_turn_async(game_instance):
        game_instance.__ensure_calc_thread()
        game_instance._calc_queue.put("go") # <- signals the "driver"to start calculating.
        # even if this is called more than once, the next call to "__handle_enemy_turn" will
        # just take place after the first one finihes running, and sets `__player_turn`.

    def __handle_enemy_turn(self):
        '''Обработка хода противника (компьютера)'''
        self.__player_turn = False
        ...
        self.__player_turn = True
        self.__check_for_game_over()


